# WebKit Crashes trying to play _any_ flash content

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a curious problem with WebKit and WebView. All my other URLs seem to work fine, but when I try to load a site with a lot of flash content, the whole app crashes. The app again functions fine if I customize webview to prevent plugins from running.

What's more curious is my dev machine seems to be the exception with all the content playing fine, but all the other PCs I've tried it in crashed. The site however, opens up fine if I open it in safari.

Any tips?

Edit: Oops, sorry, was having a long day at work. Anyway, thanks to @Miraaj, I've got about 80% of the issues fixed. Now, for the rest of them, I get a message in Xcode that says - `Previous frame inner to this frame (gdb could not unwind past this frame)`. I can't replicate the issue right now, but I'll post the `backtrace` output the next time I Have this issue. HTH.

Thanks, 
Teja.

Comment: You need to post the crash log, and/or the console log. I mean, do you expect us to be psychics who can see how your program crashed on various machines? Or do you think we're super hackers who can track from your ID the computer you used and see the crash log ourselves? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check last message in Debugger Console before the crash, if it shows message such as "Debugger() called" then ensure that Run > Stop on Debugger() / DebugStr() is deselected.

Hope this helps,

Miraaj

Comment: Wow. How in the world did you answer that! Thanks, that fixes about 80% of the problem. The other 20% of the cases, I've edited the description, any help on that is much appreciated too!

Comment: Btw, why does this happen? They're just some websites I'm pulling up. Does this mean they have a `Debugger` call in the page's HTML that's triggering the XCode debugger?

Comment: No, Adobe's engineer decided to keep `Debugger` call in their flash plugin, in the shipped version! That's triggering XCode debugger.

Comment: Are you being serious? It's kinda hard to detect sarcasm on the internet. :S